# SQL Combining columns for a total from different tables

Tags: sql, database, join, group-by, sum

Table 1 (ID, State)
Table 2 (ID, Cost)
*Unique Identifier = ID

What We Have

```
Select ID, State, Cost
From Table 1 A
Left Join Table 2 B On b.ID = a.ID

ID  State   Cost
A1  WA      100
B1  OR      175
C1  NV      115
A1  TX      75
B1  OR  125
```

What We Want

```
ID  Total
A1  175
B1  300
C1  115
```

I’m looking to combine columns from a separate tables

So what we're trying to do is calculate the totals across any and all states for any particular ID. As you can see the state and Cost columns come from different tables. From my understanding it is not just a simple SUM query it would require some sort of nesting but i'm not sure how... the tables can be joined on ID

Comment: You've said what "we" want, but  what are you (plural?) asking? What have you tried? Why wouldn't a "simply" `SUM` work when that looks like that's exactly what would work.

Comment: Deja vu. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, (whoops forgot to mention) you tagged 2 *very* different RDBMS; MySQL and SQL Server. What RDBMS are you *really* using. I can removed the conflicting tags, please [edit] back in the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

For this dataset, you can simply aggregate `table2`, since it contains both columns you need (that is, `id` and `cost`).

```
select id, sum(cost) total from table2 group by id
```

If you are looking to exclude `id`s that do not exists in `table1`:

```
select id, sum(cost) total 
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
group by id
```

Comment: What does the "1" represent in the "Select 1" portion of the nest?

Comment: @shade206: it is a subquery for an `exists` condition. Since all we want to know is whether rows *exist* that satisfy the conditions, the subquery’s result is discarded anyway, hence `select 1`.